# Is it necessary to persist refresh token in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, identity

I am using resource owner password flow and i got successfully access token and refresh token and i did not persist any token in database and everything works fine locally.
But when i deploy identity server in production refresh token is not working as expected.
i have set access token expired time 20 minutes and refresh token expiry time 7 days.

if i refresh access token within 20 minutes or before expiry of access token then refresh token refresh access token and work as expected but after expiry of access token refresh token does not refresh access token and throw invalid_grant error.

As i did not save refresh token in database and i searched on google but answers are confusion.

So can anyone tell me :

Do i need to store refresh token while it is working fine locally without storing ? if yes any implementation reference i am using mysql as database.

or something else i need to look.

Thank you.

Your response is valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

When running IdentityServer4 locally and "out of the box", things like refresh tokens aren't persisted and that's usually fine in the early stages of development.

When planning to deploy your Identity Provider to a server however, you'll need an operational store anyway (for storing grants, user consent, etc.).
This operational store can also store refresh tokens and reference tokens (read up on it in the [IdentityServer4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/ef.html#operational-store-support-for-authorization-grants-consents-and-tokens-refresh-and-reference)).

Setting up token storage on the IdP is a good idea. Storing tokens opens the door to clean token revocation. A cleanly implemented sign-out in a client application would call the token revocation endpoint on your IdP. That's because when a user logs out, neither the access token nor the refresh token is needed any longer.

You can also revoke tokens from your end, making subsequent API calls fail for that access token and there are some compelling use cases for that as well.

Comment: Thank you . Yes now I am storing token.